# How to 301 redirect all other URLs that do not meet conditions using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am doing bunch of 301 redirects via the htaccess file for a WordPress website. I have listed about 80 specific URLs/directories that point to their new relative position on a new domain.

However, there are still a bunch of URLs that are lurking around, that I want to redirect to the new domains home page.

What I am trying to do is if the URL does not meet any of the hardcoded URLs, redirect it to the home page.

Here is what I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Begin Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^2015/12/14/some\-directory/$ https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^2015/14/14/someother\-directory/$ https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
# End Redirects
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code that I am using to catch all other URLs and send to the home page is written as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

The issue I am having is that it seems to jump straight to that condition, redirecting all the URLs to the home page, whether that piece of code is at the top of the htaccess file or the bottom. Is there a way to set this as a condition so it only redirects the URL if it does not meet any of the URLs or directories above it?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `RewriteRule` can't be used like that, which normally we'll write it like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2015/12/14/some-directory/
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Where your code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^2015/12/14/some\-directory/$ https://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Also, you could test your `.htaccess` with [this tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) first which can save your time from transferring file between server and clearing cache (if you need).

Second, I don't really see the meaning of your code, since all URLs from `www.olddomain.com` will be redirected to `https://www.newdomain.com/?`. Unless you meant, redirect base on the path but not the domain, which you'll need to remove the first line of my code.

Last, notice I didn't add `$` behind the path, since I'm not really sure if you need a wildcard redirect which `/2015/12/14/some-directory/something` also redirects to `https://www.newdomain.com/?`. If you don't, remember to add it back.